# What is RSACryptoServiceProvider doing under the hood when Encrypting using RSA?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

When I drill down into the .Net source code I cannot find the code that actually runs when rsa.Encrypt is called, maybe it's running code within a DLL because I cannot find where the method is overridden

Please can you point me to the source code of the function rsa.Encrypt or explain what it is doing here to encrypt a byte array (keeping each value 0>255)

I've tried drilling down into the .net source code

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsa.cs

I have tried to step into the code to debug it (it just skips over without stepping into)

I've tried to understand how RSA can encrypt numbers whilst keeping them within an integer ring (i.e 0>255)

```
    public byte[] Encrypt(string publicKeyXML, string dataToEncript)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKeyXML);
        return rsa.Encrypt(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToEncript), true);
    }
```

I expect the .net source to be browsable to the source code of the overridden function

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "0>255". It's not a standard math notation. Can you clarify please?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using to debug the code? These debugging instructions (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html) are geared toward Visual Studio 2013, but I think they should apply to later versions of VS as well. The following debugging options need to be set:  Disable just my code, Disable step over properties and operators, Disable require source files to exactly match the original version, Enable .NET framework source stepping, Enable source server support

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_RSACryptoServiceProvider_Encrypt_System_Byte___System_Boolean_) clearly lists RSA with OAEP padding as specified in [PKCS#1 v2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2437) with the latest version being [PKCS#1 v2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1) (linking to the specification of OAEP in this later version). It however doesn't specify the hash function used for MGF1, but you can be pretty sure it is the default SHA-1 function (which, in this case, isn't a direct security issue). So I am not entirely sure why you would try to read the source code if the algorithm is well defined by a standard.

Answer (score 0):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt` just calls Windows `CryptEncrypt`, so you wouldn’t find your answer anyways.

You seem to be under the impression that it operates on bytes during the RSA operation, but really it operates on bits, or numbers, depending on how you want to think about it.

A 32-bit integer value 253 plus a 32-bit integer value 5 produces the 32-bit value 258, but at the byte level `{ FD, 00, 00, 00 }` + `{ 05, 00, 00, 00 }` = `{ 02, 01, 00, 00 }` (Little endian hex). The operation makes more sense at the number level, or bit level, than the byte level... but addition still makes easy sense at the byte level.

If you really want to understand what is happening, you can step through `BigInteger.ModPow`, which is a managed implementation of the main operation involved in RSA. The purpose of the BigInteger type is to work with numbers without a 32- or 64- bit space limitation.